# How to load an JPEG image into a char array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, image, jpeg

i want to store an JPEG image into a normal unsigned char array, i'd used ifstream to store it; however, when i checked if the array i'd stored is correct or not ( by rewrite it again to an JPEG image), the image that i rewrote by using the stored array couldn't show correctly, so i think the problem must come from the technique that i use to store the image into an array is not correct. I want an array which can be stored perfectly so that i can use it to rewrite back into a JPEG image again.I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me solve this problem!

```
int size = 921600;
    unsigned char output[size];
    int i = 0;

    ifstream DataFile;
    DataFile.open("abc.jpeg");
    while(!DataFile.eof()){
        DataFile >> output[i];
        i++;
    }
    /* i try to rewrite the above array into a new image here */
    FILE * image2;
    image2 = fopen("def.jpeg", "w");
    fwrite(output,1,921600, image2);
    fclose(image2);
```

Comment: JPEG has its specific structure. It's not just raw pixel values stored in some file. Consider using an existing library that does it for you..
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure

Comment: indeed, use a JPEG I/O library.

Comment: Why don't you use fopen() then fread() instead of your while loop, read the entire file into the buffer?

Comment: @AlexG Irrelevant if you're just copying its bytes.

Comment: The very first mistake in your code is you didn't open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the shown code.

```
while(!DataFile.eof()){
```

This is [always a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). See the linked question for a detailed explanation.

```
    DataFile >> output[i];
```

The formatted extraction operator, `>>`, by definition, skips over all white space characters and ignores them. Your jpg file surely has bytes 0x09, 0x20, and a few others, somewhere in it, and this automatically skips over and does not read them.

In order to do this correctly, you need to [use read() and gcount()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read your binary file. Using `gcount()` correctly should also result in your code detecting the end-of-file condition properly.

Comment: "This is always a bug". Not always, but in the form shown above yes.

Comment: File needs to be opened in binary mode too

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add error check when opening files. Find the file size and read in to the buffer according to the filesize.

You might also look in to using `std::vector<unsigned char>` for character storage.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream DataFile("abc.jpeg", std::ios::binary);
    if(!DataFile.good())
        return 0;

    DataFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t filesize = (int)DataFile.tellg();
    DataFile.seekg(0);

    unsigned char output[filesize];
    //or std::vector
    //or unsigned char *output = new unsigned char[filesize];
    if(DataFile.read((char*)output, filesize))
    {
        std::ofstream fout("def.jpeg", std::ios::binary);
        if(!fout.good())
            return 0;
        fout.write((char*)output, filesize);
    }

    return 0;
}
```